# Serializing objects with nullable nested lists

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following objects that I want to serialize:

```
class Account
{
    public Account(List<string> groups)
    {
        Groups = groups.Select(s=>new Group(s)).ToList();
    }
    [JsonProperty("Groups")]
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
class Group
{
    public Group(string url)
    {
        Url = url;
    }

    public CommentSchedule NextCommentSchedule()
    {
        if (CommentSchedules.Count == 0) return null;
        return CommentSchedules.Aggregate((curMin, x) => x.StartTime < curMin.StartTime ? x : curMin); // Result of inside function goes to curMin, next item in list goes to x
    }

    [JsonProperty("Url")] 
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Comments")]
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CommentSchedules")]
    public List<CommentSchedule> CommentSchedules { get; set; }
}
class Comment
{
    public Comment(string text, int max)
    {
        Text = text;
        MaxPosts = max;
    }
    [JsonProperty("Text")] // Text to post
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("MaxPosts")] // Maximum number of times comment can be posted before being removed
    public int MaxPosts { get; set; }
}
```

I have no problem deserializing it into the file I'm saving it in, and I can serialize the string when there are no groups, but when I try to serialize the json string after adding a group I get

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'Groups', line 1, position 67.

I'm pretty sure this is because I'm saving it with empty lists inside of the groups so when it tries to serialize the empty nested lists it doesn't like that. How can I fix this?

Comment: Add a constructor to the Class initializing the List object like : Comments = new List<Comments>();

Comment: I tried that, also tried : Comments = new List<Comment>();
            Comments.Add(new Comment("IGNORE",0));
            CommentSchedules = new List<CommentSchedule>();
            CommentSchedules.Add(new CommentSchedule(DateTime.MaxValue, DateTime.MaxValue, 0));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that your `Account` class does not have a public parameterless constructor.  Instead, it has a single parameterized constructor, like so:

```
class Account
{
    public Account(List<string> groups)
    {
        Groups = groups.Select(s=>new Group(s)).ToList();
    }
    [JsonProperty("Groups")]
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}
```

When Json.NET tries to deserialize such a class, it will construct a class instance by calling that constructor, *matching the constructor arguments to the JSON properties by name using reflection* and using default values for missing properties.  Matching by name is *case-insensitive*, unless there are multiple matches that differ only in case, in which case the match becomes case sensitive.

Now, your constructor has a parameter named `groups` that with the same name (modulo case) as the property `Groups`.  **However, they are collections of objects of different types**.  The property returns a collection of classes that are mapped to Json.NET *objects*, whereas the constructor takes a collection of *simple strings*.  This mismatch accounts for the serialization error your are seeing, as Json.NET cannot deserialize an object as a simple string.

The workaround is to provide either a parameterless constructor, or a parameterized constructor marked with [`[JsonConstructor]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConstructorAttribute.htm) taking a `List<Group> groups` as an argument.  Either constructor can be private as long as it is marked with `[JsonConstructor]`.  I.e. either add:

```
    [JsonConstructor]
    Account()
    {
        Groups = new List<Group>();
    }
```

Or

```
    [JsonConstructor]
    Account(List<Group> groups)
    {
        Groups = groups;
    }
```

The fact that your `Comment` class only has a parameterized constructor is not a problem, since the data types of the arguments match the data types of its properties.  You might want to change the name of the `max` argument to `maxPosts` so that the value is passed to the constructor rather than set later via the property:

```
    public Comment(string text, int maxPosts)
    {
        Text = text;
        MaxPosts = maxPosts;
    }
```

More generally, if you follow the convention that your constructor arguments should have the same name (modulo case) and type as the corresponding class members, then Json.NET should be able to deserialize your class.

Comment: Appreciate this, I'll definitely bookmark it for future projects. I was able to solve the main problem by just changing the structure of the classes. Instead of having groups with comments and comment schedules, the account now has comment schedules with a list of comments and a group string. Little bit less functionality but it actually made things simpler so I'm going to keep it. Thanks for the response!